# Extract ID and rewrite URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved a website to wordpress. Therefore I want to redirect the old posts to the corresponding wordpress post.

The old url contains an id which I want to extract and map to wordpress.

Example for the old URL:

```
www.mydomain.com/include.php?BLABLAcontentid=XXBLABLA'
```

which I want to map to the new URL:

```
'www.mydomain.com/?p=XX'
```

where XX is a number containing 0-9

I'm trying to extend the wordpress rewrite by the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^include(.*)$ index%1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^include(.*)$ index$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)contentid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule .* /?p=%2 [R,L]
```

If I call 'www.mydomain.com/index.php?BLABLAcontentid=XXBLABLA' it works correctly, therefore I tried to replace include by index, but this doesn't seem to work. Any hints on how I can proceed here?

Thanks in advance and regards,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the redirect rule **before** your wordpress routing rule. The redirect needs to happen before internal routing takes place. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)contentid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^include\.php$ /?p=%2 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the solution to my problem!